# Corollary to Putnam's theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $T_1$ and $T_2$ are normal operators on Hilbert spaces $\mathcal H_1$ and $\mathcal H_2$, respectively. Putnam showed that if $X$ is an operator satisfying $T_2X=XT_1$, then $T_2^*X=XT_1^*$.

Suppose $T_1$ and $T_2$ are similar, so that there is some operator $S$ with a two-sided inverse such that $ST_1=T_2S$. How can one show that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are unitarily equivalent?

This result is mentioned in a number of papers, but I can't find a proof. There is a purported proof in the Wikipedia article on Fuglede's theorem (where a correct proof of Putnam's result can be found), but it is obviously erroneous.

Comment: It's theorem 12.36 in Rudin. Shall I reproduce the proof, or do you prefer to look it up yourself?

Comment: @DanielFischer I'll look it up. Thanks. Should I delete the question, then?

Comment: Your call. Will it help future visitors? Then one of us should post an answer. If not, delete it.

Comment: @DanielFischer I checked Rudin's book. It seems that he only addresses the case $\mathcal H_1 = \mathcal H_2$.

Comment: I saw that you wanted something more general about a minute after you deleted. Sorry for missing it at first.

Comment: @DanielFischer No problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think, however, the more general case can be reduced to the one where $\mathcal{H}_1 = \mathcal{H}_2$. Let me see if I think right.

Comment: I've added an even simpler reduction. Thought you might be interested to get a notification.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fairly straightforward to reduce it to the case $\mathcal{H}_1 = \mathcal{H}_2$ treated in Rudin's theorem 12.36.

Consider the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{H}_1 \times \mathcal{H}_2$. A linear operator on $\mathcal{H}$ decomposes

$$L = \begin{pmatrix}\alpha & \beta\\ \gamma & \delta\end{pmatrix},$$

with $\alpha \colon \mathcal{H}_1 \to \mathcal{H}_2$, $\beta \colon \mathcal{H}_2 \to \mathcal{H}_1$, $\gamma\colon \mathcal{H}_1 \to \mathcal{H}_2$ and $\delta \colon \mathcal{H}_2 \to \mathcal{H}_2$. We then have

$$\begin{pmatrix}\alpha & \beta\\ \gamma & \delta\end{pmatrix}^\ast  = \begin{pmatrix}\alpha^\ast & \gamma^\ast\\ \beta^\ast & \delta^\ast\end{pmatrix}.$$

The operators

$$N_1 = \begin{pmatrix} T_1 & 0\\0&0\end{pmatrix};\quad N_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\ 0&T_2 \end{pmatrix}$$

are then normal, and the invertible operator

$$B = \begin{pmatrix}0&S^\ast\\ S&0\end{pmatrix}$$

satisfies $BN_1 = N_2 B$. Let $S = UP$ be the polar decomposition of $S$. The polar decomposition of $B$ is then

$$B = \begin{pmatrix}0&U^\ast\\ U&0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}P&0\\ 0&UPU^\ast\end{pmatrix} = \mathscr{U}\mathscr{P}.$$

By Rudin's theorem 12.36, we have $\mathscr{U}N_1 = N_2 \mathscr{U}$, and that translates to $UT_1 = T_2 U$.

---

Of course, shortly after I turned the computer off, I saw an even simpler way to reduce the problem to theorem 12.36.

Let $S = UP$ the polar decomposition of $S$, and define $T_3 = U^\ast T U$. Then $T_3 \colon \mathcal{H}_1 \to \mathcal{H}_1$ is normal, and from $ST_1 = T_2 S$ we obtain $U^\ast ST_1 = U^\ast T_2 S = (U^\ast T_2 U)(U^\ast S) = T_3 (U^\ast S)$. The polar decomposition of $U^\ast S = U^\ast U P$ is $U^\ast S = (U^\ast U) P = I\cdot P$, so by 12.36, we have $I\cdot T_1 = T_3\cdot I$, i.e. $T_1 = U^\ast T_2 U \iff UT_1 = T_2 U$.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is well-known, but how do you produce the polar decomposition of $S$? Rudin does it only for operators $\mathcal H\rightarrow \mathcal H$ for some Hilbert space, but here $S:\mathcal H_1\rightarrow H_2$.

Comment: I'm assuming we're dealing with complex scalars. Not sure whether it works for reals. You consider $S^\ast S \colon \mathcal{H}_1 \to \mathcal{H}_1$. That's positive, so let $P = \sqrt{S^\ast S}$. Then $\lVert Px\rVert^2 = \langle Px,Px\rangle = \langle P^2 x,x\rangle = \langle S^\ast S x,x\rangle = \lVert Sx\rVert^2$. $Px \mapsto Sx$ is therefore a linear isometry. There are details left to be filled in ;) It's theorem 18.18 in the first German edition of Meise/Vogt, Introduction to Functional Analysis, should be in the same region in the English edition.